# Authenticate FastAPI with clientid/clientsecret

Tags: keycloak, fastapi

I'm trying to set up FastAPI (0.71.0) authentication with clientid-clientsecret.

I configured `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer` and apparently from the swagger (`/docs`) endpoint it looks fine, it asks for client-id and client-secret for authentication.

```py
auth = OAuth2PasswordBearer(
    authorizationUrl=AUTH_URL,
    tokenUrl=TOKEN_URL,
)

agent = FastAPI(
    description=_DESCRIPTION,
    version=VERSION,
    dependencies=[Depends(auth)],
    middleware=middlewares,
    root_path=os.getenv('BASEPATH', '/'),
    swagger_ui_init_oauth={
        'usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant': True,
        'scopes': 'openid profile email'
    }
)
```

However calling the API directly I can access with any Bearer such as:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8080/test'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer BADTOKEN', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url=url, params={}, headers=headers)
```

and `response.ok = True`, so I might be missing something in FastAPI settings but cannot see where.

Is this the correct authentication flow?

> PS: What I want to achieve is service to service communication, so the API is not getting accessed by a regular user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a look at [`OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer` implementation](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/3b2e891917dd2739659643cedb5258e65d54934d/fastapi/security/oauth2.py#L174), I ended up adding a method to check the validity of the bearer token:

```py
public_key = requests.get(ISSUER_URL).json().get('public_key')
key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' + public_key + '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'

oauth = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
        authorizationUrl=AUTH_URL,
        tokenUrl=TOKEN_URL,
)
async def auth(token: str | None = Depends(oauth)):
    try:
        jwt.decode(
            token,
            key=key,
            options={
                "verify_signature": True,
                "verify_aud": False,
                "verify_iss": ISSUER_URL
            }
        )
    except JOSEError as e:  # catches any exception
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401,
            detail=str(e))
```